# how to Use Materialize js with vue-cli

Tags: vuejs2, vue-cli

I'm using vue-cli,
i have installed materialize using "npm install materialize-css"

then i required that in my main.js file

```
require("materialize-css/dist/css/materialize.css");
require("materialize-css/dist/js/materialize.js");
```

it doesn't loads my js file.
how to include materialize.js in vue-cli. can someone guide me on this.?

Comment: I would recommend that you look into some of the component libraries that have already done the work for you.   I personally use vuetify quite a lot 1. https://vuetifyjs.com/   2. https://vuematerial.io/

Comment: Thanks @skribe, vuetifyjs is better